# Generic method using models

Tags: c#, generics

I have logs in my database for reviewing categorization of products. The method to approve a categorization is the same for each log system, although they are present in different tables in my database. To simplify things a bit, I decided to create a generic method, such as:

```
[NonAction]
public void Approve<Log>(Log log, string userId) where Log : ProductLog, CategoryLog, SubCategoryLog
{
    log.approved = true;
    log.approvedBy = userId;
}
```

Where ProductLog, CategoryLog, SubCategoryLog are Models from my Asp.Net MVC project.

The problem is, I get the following error:

> The class type constraint 'CategoryLog' must come before any other constraints

I get the same error for SubCategoryLog

Note that ProductLog, SubCategoryLog, and CategoryLog are generated classes from Entity Framework Database First.

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Do `ProductLog`, `CategoryLog`, or `SubCategoryLog` all inherit from a common base class or implement a common interface, such as `ILog`? If so, that should be your constraint for your generic method. And if they don't have one of those, then add one!

Comment: do you have an interface? `ILog`?

Comment: No, I don't. Could you help with a code snipped? I read about interfaces in the C# Manual, but I can't figure out how to adapt it to my problem. Besides, I am using Database First and I don't want to alter the automatically generated Models.

Comment: If you don't know how to modify models generated by Database First, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348734/generating-interfaces-from-entity-framework-database-first-auto-generated-code).

Comment: I think I got it working! Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic constraints can contain exactly one class type constraint. They are "and", not "or". So this:

```
where Log : ProductLog, CategoryLog, SubCategoryLog
```

Is interpreted as three class type constraints, which is not supported, because C# doesn't have multiple inheritance. You *can't* have a type that inherits these three types.

Now you say:

> I am using Database First

So I assume that those three types have the same properties that you wish to set in this generic method. Both problems are solved at once by introducing an interface and applying that to the partial classes of those entities:

```
public interface ILog
{
    bool approved { get; set; }
    string approvedBy { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductLog : ILog
{
}

public partial class CategoryLog : ILog
{
}

public partial class SubCategoryLog : ILog
{
}
```

Now you can constrain your generic method to that interface:

```
public void Approve<TLog>(TLog log, string userId) where TLog : ILog
```

And as indicated by [@pseudoDust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1675532/pseudodust), in this case you won't even need generics anymore, just the interface:

```
public void Approve(ILog log, string userId)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: With an interface, the generic can be avoided all together: `public void Approve(ILog log, string userId)`