# Use reflection and lambda expression with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, reflection

I need to filter a collection of items by verifing the value of a flag named `deletion_date`

```
 public List<T> GetAll()
 {
   if (context == null) context = new ajtdevEntities();
   return context.Set<T>().Where(p => p.GetType().GetProperty("deletion_date") == null).ToList();
 }
```

I get an exception when I used this generic method

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ' System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty ( System.String )' , and the latter can not be translated into term store.

How can I fix this method?

Comment: Don't use reflection,even less with linq-to-entities which doesn't support it. Why don't you have a method `GetAllUsers` and one `GetAllFoo` and so on`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of reflection, you can build the filter expression manually using `System.Linq.Expressions` like this:

```
public List<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "deletion_date"), Expression.Constant(null)),
        parameter);
    if (context == null) context = new ajtdevEntities();
    return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Note that the above will throw exception if your type does not have property/field called "deletion_date" or the type of the property does not support `null`. But the same can be said for your reflection based implementation (if it worked).

Answer (score 3):

An ORM will inspect the lambda and convert its parts to SQL. The Entity Framework team chose not to support reflection, and rightfully so. So it can't translate `GetProperty()` calls to SQL, hence the error you get.

It wouldn't work anyway, because `GetProperty()` gets a `PropertyInfo` instance, not the value. So if it were `null`, that would indicate that the type of `p` has no property named `deletion_date`.

The proper way would be to call `GetValue()` on the `PropertyInfo` (note that this will throw a `NullReferenceException` if there is no property named thusly):

```
p => p.GetType().GetProperty("deletion_date").GetValue(p)
```

But again, reflection is not supported in Entity Framework, so you want to use interfaces:

```
public interface IDeletable
{
    DateTime? deletion_date { get; set; }
}
```

And apply that to your class or method as a generic constraint. Then you can use it in your lambda:

```
public class WhateverClass<T>
    where T : IDeletable
{
    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Where(p => p.deletion_date == null).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I can't implement the interface `IDeletable` interface for all the `T` because the `T` class are auto-generated(from edmx)

Comment: You can, because they are [generated as partial classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044596/making-entity-framework-implement-an-interface).

Comment: But I have to edit it in every re-generation of the model !!

Comment: No, you don't, they are partial classes. Create a new file, using the same namespace as your EDMX entities, in which you create partial classes like `public partial class SomeEntity : IDeletable { }` and you're good to go. Try searching, see for example [Generating Interfaces from entity framework database first auto-generated code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348734/generating-interfaces-from-entity-framework-database-first-auto-generated-code).

Comment: Yes I know but assume I add couples of entities to the model so I have to add the implementation of the interface for the new class everytime

Comment: Yes, every time you add a new entity which you want to use with this generic repository or whatever it is, you'll have to create a matching second partial class and apply the interface to that entity.